# Passing hive configuration with aws emr cli

Tags: amazon-web-services, hive, emr, aws-cli, amazon-emr

I am following doc: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ElasticMapReduce/latest/ReleaseGuide/emr-dev-create-metastore-outside.html  and trying to create emr cluster using the **awscli==1.10.38** .

I use the following command as mentioned in the documentation:

```
aws emr create-cluster --release-label emr-5.0.0 --instance-type m3.xlarge --instance-count 2 \
--applications Name=Hive --configurations ./hiveConfiguration.json --use-default-roles
```

I am also using the exact same hiveConfiguration.json as mentioned in the document.

but it says **"aws: error: invalid json argument for option --configurations"**

Why do I get the error?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your argument to `--configurations` is incorrect. Missing **file://**  CLI needs to know you are specifying a file or S3 object.

```
aws emr create-cluster --configurations file://hiveConfiguration.json
```